# Integrating Brownian motion against another Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Suppose that $B$ is $d$-dimensional Brownian motion, where each of the $d$ coordinates $B^i$ is an independent Brownian motion over $\mathbb R$. Then, can the integral below be understood as an Itô integral?

$$\int_s^t B^i dB^j, 0\le s < t$$

I know that it can in the case that $i=j$, and it yields $\tfrac{1}{2} (B^i)^2 - \tfrac{t-s}{2}$. What about the other case?

Comment: It makes sense as an Itô integral. It is the limit in probability of the corresponding Riemann sums, and moreover, this is essentially not different from an integral of the form $\int f_s \, \mathrm{d}W_s$ for a deterministic $f$ and a BM $W$ (via conditioning on sample paths of $B^i$).

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

By the [integration-by-parts formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus#Integration_by_parts) (which is a special case of the two-dimensional Ito-formula)
$$
B^i_tB^j_t-B^i_sB^j_s=\int_s^t B^i_u\,dB^j_u+\int_s^t B^j_u\,dB^i_u+\langle B^i,B^j \rangle_t -\langle B^i,B^j \rangle_s\,.
$$
In your case the covariation terms vanish.